# Angular - How to get current url in app component

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am trying to get current url of application in `AppComponent` but it always returns the root path `/`. Example, if I visit `/users` in new tab, the expected result should be `/users`, but when I check in the console, it shows
`/`.

However, it works when I do the same in a child component. Below are my code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})

export class AppComponent {
    constructor(router: Router) {    
        console.log(this.router.url) // return '/'    
    }
}
```

How is that possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can subscribe to `router.events` and filter for **NavigationEnd** event to get the current active route url.

```
this.router.events.subscribe((e) => {
  if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    console.log(e.url);
  }
});
```

mention this will fail if that's no valid router defined.

Comment: YES!  Observing for "NavigationEnd" event works if you're trying to get the full route + parameters from app.component (or any other components that are parents of the module defined for that route).  Eg, I have a route '/product/category/:id' and I need to identify this from a 'navbar component' that is outside of my 'product module'.  Using @Pengyy's solution, I can now see the exact url route entered into the browser: '/product/cars/1'.

Comment: Note - for my purposes, I ended up using [RouterLinkActive] to assign an 'active' css class to my nav button.  But use @Pengyy's solution for any other purposes where you need the route from a parent module.

Comment: How you can get full url, including a domains: `https://demo.domain.com` -> how to get `demo.domain.com` ?

Comment: @SkorunkaFrantišek you can use `window.location.host` to retrieve the host part.

Answer (score 7):

In Angular 4, you can get the *full path string* from within app.component.ts by using the Location module.

Eg, In your browser, when you navigate to "http://yoursite.com/products/cars?color=red&model=202", the code below will output pathString "/products/cars?color=red&model=202".

In app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router} from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

    constructor(
    private location: Location
  ) { 
      var pathString = location.path();
      console.log('appComponent: pathString...');
      console.log(pathString);       
  }
}
```

*Credit: https://tutorialedge.net/post/typescript/angular/angular-get-current-route-location/

Comment: One advantage to doing it this way is that the full path is available before any child modules are loaded.  Thus if you are using a global var to hold a state enumerator, you could read that variable to configure the child modules as they load.

Comment: It is working nicely at first start.
If I go between different sublinks.. - the url is not updating. It needs F5 for page refresh. :-(
I'll search for another option.

Thanks for the proposal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the current url, use the `ActivatedRoute` instead.
In your constructor add it like this

```
 constructor(
 private router: Router,  
 private route: ActivatedRoute) {    
     route.params.subscribe(p => {
      //let's say you want to get id parameter.
         console.log(p['id']);
  }); 
    }
```

Comment: Can be also: `this.route.snapshot.params['id']` or even `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')`.

Comment: You should probably subscribe to the url property, not params. Anyways, this fails to determine url on fresh load.

Answer (score 0):

for the very first access to the SPA, it seems that the current url app is not always accessible through an Angular way. No route has been loaded yet, but you still may need to access the requested url for some internal processes.

So I did this :

```
let strings = window.location.href.split(window.location.host);
let url = strings[strings.length-1];
```

Answer (score -10):

you recursively iterate parent property until you reach topmost element which corresponds to root of your app.