# Obtain the url from app.component.ts angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have Angular (version 8) application with `app.component.ts` file and inside I wish to get the url:

```
ngOnInit() {
   // Get url
  }
```

The URL is similar to like this `http://localhost:4205/#/year/month/?user=fox`. I have necessity to get the url from this point in order to setup the application getting from the server the information.

I have tried to use:

```
this.router.routerState.snapshot.url
```

where `router` is `private router: Router` but it returns an empty-string.

In others words my app file is similar to:

```
 constructor(
    private readonly store: Store<any>,
    private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit() {
     const splitUrl = this.router.routerState.snapshot.url.split('/')
  }
[...]
```

But the `splitUrl` is empty.

Is there a solution in order to get the url with all parameters in this position?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 - How to get current url in app component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44621887/angular-2-how-to-get-current-url-in-app-component)

Comment: If it is a one-time setup, you can use `location.href`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If the component outside of `router-outlet`:

You can access this URL by subscribing to the `route.events`:

```
import { Route } from '@angular/compiler/src/core';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd, Router, UrlSegment } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(private route: Router){

  }
  title = 'angular-example';

  ngOnInit(){
    this.route.events.subscribe(res=>{
      if(res instanceof NavigationEnd){
        console.log(res.url);
      }
    })
  }
}
```

[image]

### If the component inside of `router-outlet`:

```
export class StudentsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.router.routerState.snapshot.url)
  }
```

In this case you can use the `this.router.routerState.snapshot.url`.

[image]

Comment: I thank you, but I have a problem with a subscription:
      this.router.events.subscribe((e) => {
        if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          this.store.dispatch(new SetUp(e.url));
          console.log(e.url);
        }
      });
      this.store.dispatch(new SetUp({user:'1'})); // I wish to remove it but I cannot 
    }
Is there a solution without the subscription?

Comment: If you have a store in your app, the better approach is to keep your route management data inside the store. If you use the `ngrx` you can try to install `@ngrx/router-store`

Comment: Yes, I use `nrgx`. I have installed `@ngrx/router-store` have you an example to use it around my problem?

Comment: You can follow this tutorial https://dev.to/salimchemes/how-to-implement-ngrx-router-store-4552

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with activatedRoute, like this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.url?

Comment: Yes, I have tested but I receive as output: undefined:

 private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
 console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.url);

Comment: Visit this page : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44621887/angular-2-how-to-get-current-url-in-app-component