# Add parameter to a route and use in a conditional

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic4

I have a simple routing like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'scenario',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/scenarios/scenario/scenario.module').then( m => m.ScenarioPageModule)
  }
 ]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

As you can see I have a "scenario" view so in my app.component.ts I have this to navigate that route:

```
this.navController.navigateRoot('scenario');
```

So, the current path is: `http://localhost:8100/scenario`

Now, I want to have a condition in my app.component.ts if that route contains a specific parameter like `http://localhost:8100/scenario/?id=C3E1EE21-A62C-452F-BE0D-AC3EF5449F23`
do something special.
What should I do to routing to accept parameter id, then in app.component.ts read if parameter comes, do a simple if like:

```
if(url.contains(parameter))
{

}
```

How can I achieve this? Regards

**UPDATE**

I tried to use on app.component.ts

```
    import { ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd, Router, UrlSegment } from '@angular/router';


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(
private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
)

ngOnInit(){
  
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      var name = params['name'];
      console.log(name)
    });
  }
```

But got undefined on console.log, do I need to change something on the route module in order to accept parameters? because parameter got deleted when I look for: `http://localhost:8100/scenario/?id=C3E1EE21-A62C-452F-BE0D-AC3EF5449F23`

So I try to add in route module a new path like:

```
{
    path: 'scenario/:id',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/scenarios/scenario/scenario.module').then( m => m.ScenarioPageModule)
  },
```

but throwing same result

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67771448/obtain-the-url-from-app-component-ts-angular?

Comment: @MishaMashina Yes, this solved the url obtain on app.component, thanks! now I want to know how can I solve the URL parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I can not access to route use activated route or route, so I use an alternative.

Created a method to get parameter with pure js

```
 getParameter() {
     if (document.URL.indexOf("?") > 0) {
         let splitURL = document.URL.split("?");
         let splitParams = splitURL[1].split("&");
         let i: any;
         for (i in splitParams){
             let singleURLParam = splitParams[i].split('=');
             if (singleURLParam[0] == "id"){
                 this.id = singleURLParam[1];
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Now I can access it using `this.id`

Comment: Maybe you should consider [Guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access) instead of checking the url directly.

Comment: Why is better something like that? it is bad practice to check URL directly? @nemoinho

Answer (score 1):

Specify your query parameter name ('id' in this case, not 'name'):

```
    ngOnInit() {
        this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
            var name = params['id'];
            console.log(name)
          });
    }
```

and don't use /:id - it designed for complex routes (like http://localhost:8100/scenario/id):

```
    {
        path: "scenario",
        loadChildren: () =>
            import('./pages/scenarios/scenario/scenario.module').then(m => m.ScenarioPageModule),
    },
```

Comment: I tried but still getting undefined

Comment: Inside AppComponent the subscription will be called [twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39861547/angular2-query-params-subscription-fires-twice/51059682) - first with 'undefined' value, second with 'C3E1EE21...' value. If you want only one subscribe call - use `this.activatedRoute.queryParams.pipe(skip(1)).subscribe(...)` or move it into ScenarioComponent ngOnInit() method.

Answer (score 0):

to get the query params from the component, you can use `ActivatedRoute` service:

from your component:

```js
construction(private route: ActivatedRoute,
(...)
)

// then you can subscribe to the query string params from your functions with

   this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
     this.name = params['name']; // 
   });
```

You can find more info about the router service in [Angular's website](https://angular.io/guide/router#getting-route-information)

Comment: I tried with url: `http://localhost:8100/scenario/?id=C3E1EE21-A62C-452F-BE0D-AC3EF5449F23`, but got undefined. Do I need change something on router?

Comment: you might have something else routing before angular starts processing your intended component... might also be because of lazy loading... maybe you'll need a service at app.component to store the parameters (thi the method above) and then you can get the value from the service

Comment: I use the RouterModule for routing, I added it at the beginning of my question, after routes declaration, but nothing special